# How to dockerize Jhipster monolothic Angular application as docker folder is missing in Client application

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, jhipster, docker-maven-plugin

I am using latest Jhipster vesion v7.0.1 and generated monolithic client application [angular] and separate monolithic server application.
I want to create separate docker image for these two application.
But observed that **Docker Folder** is not generated in client application.

Can any one please help me here to achieve this dockerization.

Comment: Have you read the docs? It uses jib from maven or gradle. https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#-building-and-running-a-docker-image-of-your-application

Comment: Thanks you for reply. Yes I went through doc but my requirement is to create separate client app docker image. For that I have generated separate client application using 'jhipster --skip-server' command. 
And when I am trying to dockerize generated project it gives me error that 'app.yml' is missing as Docker folder is not generated in client application.
- Tried to add app.yml manually but it is not working as expected.

I am new to Jhipster could you please guide me to achieve this dockerization task.

Comment: Could you explain why you want separate containers for client and server? You will have to deal with CORS issues unless you use a reverse proxy. Separating client and server in different source folders does not mean you have to deploy them in distinct containers. Anyway, if you really want create a docker image for the angular part only, you must decide how you will serve the bundle : using spring boot would not make any sense because you separated client from server. So a good solution would be to use nginx and write your dockerfile from nginx standard image. There are plenty of examples.